# css issue with fieldset

Tags: css, fieldset

Hi all I have written the following css to align the controls, when I am using the css with out field-set it is displaying as per required, but when I use field-set it is not displaying so can some one help me

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="divAlign">
    <div class="displayBlock">
        <div class="label">
            <label>Name:</label>
        </div>
          <div class="control">
        <input type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<fieldset style=" width: 225px;">
    <legend>Details</legend>
       <div class="divAlign">
    <div class="displayBlock">
        <div class="label">
            <label>Name:</label>
        </div>
          <div class="control">
        <input type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uj2Z9/1/

Comment: what is not aligned ? what exactly you want?

Comment: I would like to show exactly as per the display I am having on my left hand side display which is not in fieldset

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: for me they both are same (in Mozilla). you need to be clear what exactly you want to align.

Comment: This way I need http://jsfiddle.net/2nyfr/7/ with out using the properties ` display: table-cell;display:table and display: table-row;`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove default styles for the `fieldset`. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uj2Z9/2/

Comment: @Dotnet : is this your answer ?

Comment: Hi but the label control and text control should be in the same line, and I don't want to use the property `display: table-cell;`

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/2nyfr/7/` like this I need with out using the property `display: table-cell`